# Created UItextfield programmatically, how to get text later?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I've created a uitextfield programmatically when the view is loaded. If a button is pressed after it loads, though, how do I get the text from that uitextfield in a later void?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
 UITextField *fldcard= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 293, 25)];
    fldcard.placeholder = @"card";
    fldcard.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [fldcard setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.53 blue:0.23 alpha:1.0]];
    [fldcard.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [fldcard.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:fldcard];
    [fldcard release];
}

-(void)myAction:(id)sender {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSLog(@"fldcard %@", fldcard.text);
}
```

Comment: Use an instance variable to keep a reference to the text field.

Comment: Please read the description for the xcode tag. This question does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .m file under:

```
@interface YourViewController ()
{
   UITextField *fldcard;
}
@end
```

Then take out UITextField when you init fldcard. You will be able to get that UITextField for any method in that class.

Comment: Or add the ivar to the `@implementation`. No need to add a class extension just for an ivar. Though it is just as correct.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not working. I'm just getting a null response.

Comment: @user2495313 Did you assign the text field you created in `viewDidLoad` to this new instance variable?